# scrape data from selected layer using Rcurl

Tags: rcurl

I recently started with R, and got the advice to use `RCurl` when I was looking for soil data from the website http://www.bodemdata.nl (a dutch site with soil data).

The query starts with a map of the Netherlands (a png-file, `visible` when the button `"bodemdata"` is selected). A table with output is generated after selection of a part of the map (using the information button).

Is it anyway possible to make a selection box on top of the png-file using RCurl?

Please, can someone give me a hint how to collect data from a certain location on the map? (and this is probably not the easiest way to start with R...)

Comment: You generally can't think about RCurl (or curl in general) working for interactive web features. You need to figure out what the underlying application is doing and try to tap into that.

Comment: Hi @Thomas. Then is there any recommend packages that can extract data from interactive in R? Thanks